# How to create shortcode to display custom field value on a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, shortcode

in my ad site I was trying to create shortcode of some custom fields I created on a custom post type.

I'll explain

In the single post, there are the custom fields and are shown in a standard way in a table below.

If I want to take 1 of those custom filed, and add a shortcode to it and then show that custom filed easily where I want via the shortcode, how do you do it?

I hope I explained myself. I'm sure it's possible, but I can not try it for days.

I do not use the ACF plugin so I have to do it without this plugin, because everything is already set up in a plugin, not in the theme.

Answer (score 2):

You’ll have to use `add_shortcode` to achieve this. Let’s say that you want this shortcode to be called “my_cf”:

```
function my_cf_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'my_cf' );

    return get_post_meta( $atts['post_id'], <FIELD_NAME>, true );
}
add_shortcode( 'my_cf', 'my_cf_shortcode_callback' );
```

Now you can use it by putting `[my_cf]` or `[my_cf post_id=POST_ID]` to your posts.

Comment: Do I have to copy the code to function.php? enter the name of the custom field and the name of the shortcode. At that point I can go for example on elementor, add the shortcode on the single ad, personalizing it and you will see the custom field in a dynamic way?

For example, if this custom field that interests me, talk about colors. In each post I set a different color in a post there is written "green color" in another post "orange" so the custom field will show dynamically even with the shortcode?

Comment: Yes - you should paste that code to your functions.php. And you have to change `<FIELD_NAME>` to real name of your custom field. Of course you can also change name of shortcode to whatever you like by replacing `my_cf`.

Comment: iI try but wordpress give me error, no save. Why

Comment: is not this the code? add_shortcode( "sinle_post", function( $args ) {
    ob_start();
    if( isset( $args["post_id"] ) ) {
        $post_id = $args["post_id"];
    } else {
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
    }

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: This error show " Your PHP code changes have been canceled due to an error on line 0 of the Unknown file. Correct and try to save again.

Exception thrown without a stack frame "

Comment: If you’ll change the field name and paste the code correctly, then no errors should occur.

Comment: please see this page https://www.annuncigratuiti.com/prova-478.html and check custom field like "chilometri" "carburante" "cambio" i no find where is nama or value of this custom filed, and i cant create shortcode. I use wpadvert plugin with custom field addon. But i want find custom field value after i create one, and after create shortcode for personalize position

Comment: Great!
I should obtain the source path of a Custom Field "File / Image / Video".
Using the above code, I see printed "Array". How could I get the URL of the file?
Thanks!

Comment: @LucaCasati don't post comments as solutions, I understand you don't have the reputation to comment, but by doing that your account got flagged by the anti-spammer system. Be careful as it may auto-ban you if you are not careful. I've converted your answer to a comment

Comment: @LucaCasati also, WordPress does not have "field types", you need to contact the support routes for the plugin you are using that provides file fields